# Unable to click on button using protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to click on a button using protractor.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<button class="_btn--block _btn _btn--primary" ng-transclude="" sw-type="submit" swed-busy-click="" sw-priority="primary" type="submit">
    <span>
        Continue
    </span>
</button>
```

I have tried using this but it didn't work:

```
element($('button[name="Continue"]')).click();

element(by.partialButtonText("Cont")).click()
```

Comment: You could use - 

`element($('button[sw-type="submit"]')).click()`

Comment: I have used like this, it works fine.element(by.cssContainingText('button._btn--block._btn._btn--primary', 'Continue')).click();

Answer (score 1):

element($('button[name="Continue"]')).click(); this is not a correct css since name of the button is not available COntinue is the text

You could try

```
 element($('button[sw-type="submit"][class^="btn--block _btn"]')).click()
```

Comment: `element($('button[sw-type="submit"][class^="btn--block _btn"]')).click()` this is wrong it should be in this convention 
`element(by.css('some-css')); === $('some-css');`
so selector should be:

`$('button[sw-type="submit"][class^="btn--block _btn"]').click()`

Comment: I have used like this, it works fine.element(by.cssContainingText('button._btn--block._btn._‌​btn--primary', 'Continue')).click();